# Remove list string startswith in pandas df

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

i have df rows contains lists and wants to remove the particular string combined with others.

df['res']:

```
AL1 A 15, CY1 A 16, CY1 A 20, GL1 A 17, GL1 A 62,HOH A 604, HOH A 605, L21 A 18, MG A 550, PR1 A 36, TH1 A 19, TH1 A 37, TY1 A 34, VA1 A 14, HOH A 603, VA1 A 35
```

Desired output: [ removed HOH with other number]

```
AL1 A 15, CY1 A 16, CY1 A 20, GL1 A 17, GL1 A 62, L21 A 18, MG A 550, PR1 A 36, TH1 A 19, TH1 A 37, TY1 A 34, VA1 A 14, VA1 A 35
```

I tried this:

```
data['res'].str.split().apply(lambda x: [k for k in x if k.startswith('HOH')])
```

Comment: if not k.startswith('HOH')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you use `.split()` without anything else every substring will also get split.

So this `... ,HOH A 604 ...` will split into `['...', ',' ,'HOH', 'A', '604', '...']`.

As far as I understood you want to remove every `HOH` with the following numbers right?

Doing it the `.split()` way will result in removing `HOH` only and keeping `A` & `604`.

If you use `.split(',')` with the comma as parameter then we will get everything between commas seperated.

The problem I see with `startswith` is that sometimes your strings have an additional space after the comma and sometimes they don´t (e.g. ,`HOH A 604 & , HOH A 605`)

Therefore I would suggest to use `not in` instead. BUT: aware that this removes all sub strings that contain `HOH` even if they are at the end.

try this:

```
df['res'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: [k for k in x if 'HOH' not in k])
```

The cell value is now a list of strings if you need to have a string again try this:

```
df['res'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: ','.join([k for k in x if 'HOH' not in k]))
```